# How to Generate a Report Card for Students from This Three Table with Mysql and Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables that link together. What I want to do is to generate a report card for all the students in a class.

table **students_info**

```
name      sex age students_ID
--------- --- --- -----------
Kinsley   M    12           1
Michael   m    12           2
Rhianna   f    22           3
```

Table **scores_panel**

```
1stCA 2ndCA exam students_ID subjectID
----- ----- ---- ----------- ---------
   23    15   42           1         1
   10    12    7           1         2
   43    15   62           1         3
   10    12   27           2         1
   10    12   57           2         2
   23    15   12           2         3
   11    12   27           3         1
   04    12   57           3         2
   13    25   12           3         3
```

Table **subject**

```
subjectname subjectID
----------- ---------
english             1
maths               2
biology             3
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
NAME KINSLEY
SEX M
AGE 12
```

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      23    15   42
maths        10    12    7
Biology      43    15   62
```

... and so on for all students

only one subject and scores retrieved instead of all

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$generate="SELECT students_info.name, subject.subjectname, scores_panel.1stCA, scores_panel.2ndCA, scores_panel.EXAM
FROM
students_info
LEFT JOIN
scores_panel
ON students_info.students_ID=scores_panel.students_ID
LEFT JOIN
subject
ON
subject.subjectID=scores_panel.subjectID
GROUP BY scores_panel.subjectID  ";

$fetch=mysql_query($generate);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch)or die(mysql_error()))
{
?>
**NAME:** 
<?PHP echo $row['name']; ?>
subject 1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
----------
<?PHP echo $row['subjectname']; ?>
<?PHP echo $row['1stCA']; ?>     
<?PHP echo $row['2ndCA']; ?>   
<?PHP echo $row['EXAM']; ?>

THIS IS YOUR REPORT CARD 
<?PHP } ?>
```

It  works, but displays only one subject for each student,

EXAMPLE

```
  NAME Rhianna 
    SEX F
    AGE 22
```

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      11    12   27
```

NAME KINSLEY
        SEX M
        AGE 12

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      23    15   42
```

**instead of something like this:**

```
  NAME KINSLEY
    SEX M
    AGE 12
```

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      23    15   42
maths        10    12    7
Biology      43    15   62


  NAME Rhianna 
    SEX F
    AGE 22
```

and report card follow

```
subject   1stCA 2ndCA EXAM
--------- ----- ----- ----
english      11    12   27
maths        04    12    57
Biology      13    25   12
```

... and so on for all students.

your help will e appreciate

thanks

Comment: -1 Do not scream, please.

Comment: It's well written question don't down vote for silly reasons

Comment: my thanks to everyone but 
sverpoorten answer solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are so close. Just missed `students_info.students_ID` in group by claues

```
SELECT students_info.name, subject.subjectname, scores_panel.1stCA, scores_panel.2ndCA, scores_panel.EXAM
FROM
students_info
LEFT JOIN
scores_panel
ON students_info.students_ID=scores_panel.students_ID
LEFT JOIN
subject
ON
subject.subjectID=scores_panel.subjectID
GROUP BY students_info.students_ID,scores_panel.subjectID
```

***[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/280f7/1)***

Answer (score 0):

There are some flaws in the process of acquiring and showing up data. It seems that the main flaw is the limiting 'GROUP BY'-statement. There are multiple solutions, but I'll show a simple one which only requires one query to be executed.

In fact your process consists of two loops: one loop in which you are acquiring students and one in which you want the results. It goes as follows:

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$generate="SELECT students_info.students_ID, students_info.name, subject.subjectname, scores_panel.1stCA, scores_panel.2ndCA, scores_panel.EXAM
FROM
students_info
LEFT JOIN
scores_panel
ON students_info.students_ID=scores_panel.students_ID
LEFT JOIN
subject
ON
subject.subjectID=scores_panel.subjectID
ORDER BY students_info.name ASC
";

$fetch=mysql_query($generate);
$previousId = -1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch)or die(mysql_error()))
{
    if($row['students_ID'] != $previousId)
    {
        //New student: show name [and other info]
        echo "**" . $row['name'] . "**";
        echo "subject 1stCA 2ndCA EXAM";
        echo "------------------------";

        $previousId = $row['students_ID'];
    }
    ?>
<?PHP echo $row['subjectname']; ?>
<?PHP echo $row['1stCA']; ?>     
<?PHP echo $row['2ndCA']; ?>   
<?PHP echo $row['EXAM']; ?>

THIS IS YOUR REPORT CARD
<?php
}
?>
```

What's happening? The rows of your SQL-output all contain a student id and their personalia. It has only to be shown once (together with the table header), that is when a new student shows up in the output. The variable `$previousId` is used for that. Then all data is shown in that table of grades.

If you are familiar with phpMyAdmin, you can always test your SQL-code to see what it will produce.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks bro! I'm very grateful this work fine for me, thank you very much if i need more help i will let you know               U ARE intelligent